# Simpson's Integration code with Thrust outputs different results on two machines with NVC++

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, thrust

I wrote a numerical integration code:

```
#include <thrust/inner_product.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/for_each.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/discard_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <array>

#include <iostream>


template<typename val_type, std::size_t n, std::size_t n_batch,
                template<typename...> typename Container>
struct Integrator {

    const val_type coeff;

    Integrator(val_type a, val_type b) :
        coeff((b-a)/3./static_cast<val_type>(n)) {}

    template <typename itor_type>
    void operator()(itor_type f_begin, itor_type dens_begin) {

        val_type C = this->coeff;
        auto zitor_begin = thrust::make_zip_iterator(
                            thrust::make_tuple(
                              thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),f_begin));

        auto titor_begin = make_transform_iterator(zitor_begin,
        [C](auto _tuple){ 
            
             return static_cast<val_type>(thrust::get<1>(_tuple) 
                          * (thrust::get<0>(_tuple)==0 ? C 
                                             : thrust::get<0>(_tuple)%2==0? 2.*C:4.*C)); 
        });

        auto binary_pred = [](int i,int j) { return i/n==j/n ; };

        thrust::reduce_by_key(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),  // input key
                              thrust::make_counting_iterator(static_cast<int>(n*n_batch)),
                              titor_begin,                        // input value
                                                    thrust::make_discard_iterator(),    // output key
                              dens_begin,                         // output value
                              binary_pred);
    } // end of operator()

};
```

The algorithm is a simple Simpson integration. And here is the `main.cu`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include "Integrator.hpp"

using Real = double;


constexpr std::size_t n = 1000, m = 4;
constexpr Real h = 2.*M_PI/(static_cast<Real>(n)-1.);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {


    Integrator<Real,n,m,thrust::device_vector> inttest(0,2.*M_PI);
    
    thrust::host_vector<Real> _fff(n*m), _x(n);
    thrust::device_vector<Real> fff(n*m), fint(m);
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        _x[i] = i*h;
    for (int I=0; I<m; ++I)
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
            _fff[I*n+i] = std::sin(0.5*_x[i]);
    
    fff = _fff;
    inttest(fff.begin(),fint.begin());
    
    thrust::copy(fint.begin(),fint.end(),
                  std::ostream_iterator<Real>(std::cout," "));
    std::cout << std::endl;


}
```

I compiled this code on a Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) of a Windows11 system and a Ubuntu22.4 Linux server. Compilation succeeded on both machines. (I simply used `nvc++ main.cu`)

The two systems (WSL and Ubuntu Linux) have exactly the same

- gcc version (11.3),
- cuda version (12.0) and
- nvc++ version (23.3).

However, only the Linux machine yields the correct result (should be `3.99 3.99 3.99 3.99`), while The WSL Windows11 machine yields `0 0 0 0`. And the size of the executable `a.out` file is 24Mb on WSL and 8Mb on the Linux machine, so I know something wrong must have happened, but where?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code. Could you try compiling with `nvcc` (not `nvc`) instead of `nvc++`? `nvc++` is relatively new and a HPC compiler, so maybe there are still bugs regarding WSL. You will need to add `__host__ __device__` qualifiers to your lambdas (avoid pure `__device__` lambdas) and use the `--extended-lambda` compilation flag.

Comment: @paleonix I try to add the qualifiers between `[]` and `()` of the lambda, but a compilation error occurs: `error: __host__ __device__ extended lambdas cannot be generic lambdas`

Comment: @paleonix I figured out the solution, thank you! So `nvc++` does have bugs on WSL.

Comment: @paleonix So  why should we avoid pure __device__ lambdas?

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/issues/779#issuecomment-702336832) Thrust issue. If you are ok with restricting yourself to CUDA 12 and future releases, you can also use pure device lambdas in combination with [`cuda::proclaim_return_type`](https://nvidia.github.io/libcudacxx/extended_api/functional/proclaim_return_type.html).

Comment: I guess Windows/WSL is not officially supported (yet). If you look at the CUDA toolkit installation guide for Linux, you will find [instructions for WSL](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#wsl). For the NVHPC SDK, I don't see anything related to WSL. As HPC runs mostly on Linux, it might just not be a priority, although there is an [old post](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvhpc-for-windows-10/156519/6) saying that they are working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the problem only occurs with `nvc++` and not with `nvcc`, this seems to be a compiler problem.

The NVHPC SDK (and with it the `nvc++` compiler) does not officially support Windows or WSL yet, as none of them is mentioned in the [installation guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk/hpc-sdk-install-guide/index.html) or the [release notes](https://docs.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk/hpc-sdk-release-notes/index.html#supported-platforms).