# Unable to access CUDA device with OpenACC on WSL2 Ubuntu: Error code=34

Tags: cuda, nvidia, wsl-2, openacc

I am new to using OpenACC on WSL2 with Ubuntu and have encountered an issue. I successfully installed the HPC SDK as instructed on the website, without installing CUDA separately, as the latest CUDA version was included with the HPC SDK. However, when I run the `nvaccelinfo` command, it returns

> No accelerators found. Try nvaccelinfo -v for more information.

Similarly, running `pgaccelinfo` also results in

> No accelerators found. Try pgaccelinfo -v for more information.

I have set the necessary paths, but I cannot seem to access the CUDA device. What could be causing this issue?

I have recently set up Ubuntu on WSL2 to utilize OpenACC for my programming needs. Following the instructions provided on the official website, I successfully installed the HPC SDK, which was supposed to include the necessary CUDA runtime and other components. I ensured that the relevant paths were correctly set to allow access to the installed components.

I attempted to obtain additional details by running `nvaccelinfo -v` and `pgaccelinfo -v`, but both commands resulted in the error message

> could not initialize CUDA runtime, error code=34. No accelerators found. Check the permissions on your CUDA device.

As a newcomer to this technology, I am unsure of what could be causing this problem. It seems that the CUDA device is not being recognized or accessible. I have double-checked my installation steps and ensured that the necessary paths are correctly set, but I am unable to resolve this issue on my own.

I kindly request assistance from the community to help troubleshoot this problem. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has knowledge about utilizing OpenACC on WSL2 with Ubuntu, I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to overcome this error.  Additionally, any guidance regarding the proper configuration or any additional steps that may be required to utilize OpenACC successfully on WSL2 would be extremely helpful. Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!

Comment: I would guess you have installed a display driver with WSL2. Don't do that.

Comment: @talonmies I haven't done any additional thing I read that having cuda installed on my windows was enough

Comment: @talonmies are there any additional lib or bin directories that I should include in bashrc

Comment: No. If you didn't install a driver, I suspect you will find that the HPCtoolkit isn't supported on WSL

Comment: @talonmies so what should do please tell me

Comment: There has been another recent question about problems with NVHPC on WSL: [Simpson's Integration code with Thrust outputs different results on two machines with NVC++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76220209/10107454). Unlike in the CUDA Toolkit docs, the NVHPC Toolkit docs don't mention WSL at all, so there is no official support of it, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

This means that the OpenACC runtime can't find the CUDA driver since it's not installed under default system library directory.

Try setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your environment to include `/usr/lib/wsl/lib` or where ever `libcuda.so` was installed.

See: [Windows 10 WSL Ubuntu 20.04: Fortran MPI+OpenACC+DC GPU code not running](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/windows-10-wsl-ubuntu-20-04-fortran-mpi-openacc-dc-gpu-code-not-running/242573) in the Nvidia Developer Forum.